# What file explorer can I use in Cygwin with UNIX like paths?

Tags: bash, cygwin, windows-explorer, x11

I'm fed up with using Windows Explorer as my file browser as I use
Cygwin bash as my primary command line environment.

Windows Explorer shows the full path in the address bar.
Usually, I copy that, pasting it to the cygwin command prompt as in
`cygpath ""`

I then copy paste the output of cygpath so I can
cd to it.  I've also set up cpath "Bash Shell Here"
but this only works on right clicking directories.

I've used WinSCP via SSH.
ie. Start an SSH daemon in cygwin and connect to it via WinSCP.

What file explorer can I use in Cygwin with UNIX like paths?
Is there a cygwin X Windows file explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you surround the path from Windows Explorer with single or double quotes, there is no need to use the cygpath command.

In regard to your quest for a compatible file manager, I've heard that KDE's Konqueror runs on Windows.

Comment: but use singlequotes to keep your backslashes, as in, `cd 'c:\WINDOWS\'`... You can also use cygpath with backticks if necessary, e.g.      `cd \`cygpath 'c:\WINDOWS\'\``

Comment: I did not know you could use Windows/DOS paths in Cygwin.  Previous versions of cygwin did not allow this.  This is really cool!  Thanks!  You answered my question.  When did they implement this?

Comment: They have had this functionality at least since I started using Cygwin around two years ago.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [Midnight Commander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander) (`mc`)? It's in the Cygwin package repository.